# Can RDIMM RAM be used in UDIMM-only motherboards?

Tags: memory, hardware

I built a small server for internal use. By mistake I bought 16GB of [**registered** RAM](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/PartsInfo.asp?root=&LinkBack=&ktcpartno=KVR1333D3LD4R9S/8G).

The system now does not boot, I can only hear 1 long beep followed by 2 short beeps.
The specification list of [my moherboard](http://www.asus.com/Server_Workstation/Server_Motherboards/P8BX/#specifications) claims that it only supports UDIMM modules.

Is RDIMM RAM **not compatible** with UDIMM slots or is it possible to run it in "compatibility" mode (as it happens for example with ECC RAM when used in motherboards that do not support ECC--ECC checks are simply disabled)?

If RDIMM RAM cannot be used in UDIMM slots I can be sure that those beeps signal a memory problem, otherwise I'll have to investigate some more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not compatible at all. If your motherboard doesn't support registered memory then you can't use it.